# Which flag should I use when somebody did not try anything and wants help?

Tags: discussion, flagging, close-reasons

Which flag should I use when somebody did not try anything and wants help?

I tried the off-topic, not about what is in the help-center, but the flag was declined.

Comment: Try using a downvote, those don't get declined.

Comment: From your profil It seems you are an advanced flager.It's a good idea to downvote the owner may edit it.Thanks.

Comment: What does "sb" mean here?

Comment: @Asaf somebody might know.

Comment: @quid: When the truth is found to be lies, and all the joy within you dies. Don't you want somebody to explain to you what "sb" stands for? Don't you need somebody to explain to you what "sb" stands for? Wouldn't you love somebody to explain to you what "sb" stands for? You better find somebody to explain to you what "sb" stands for, sb. (These were the original lyrics of Jefferson Airplane, by the way, and only to the advice of their producer they changed them to what we know today as "Somebody to Love".)

Comment: @Asaf see brother, so beautiful, should be: somebody.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: can't anybody find me somebody to explain what 'sb' stands for?  All you need is somebody to explain what 'sb' stands for... As for the topic of the question, Taha, the usual things to do are vote, comment, and/or downvote. There's not much else you can do besides that.

Comment: Do your friends, Asaf, treat you like a guest?

Comment: It should be mentioned that if the OP do not show their work, that does not automatically mean that question should be closed as off-topic/missing context. There are many other ways to [provide sufficient context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). See also this recent discussion: [Can we stop the “Show your work craze”?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/can-we-stop-the-show-your-work-craze)

Answer (score 6):

Technically, you used basically the correct flag.

"Should be closed, Off-topic, Lack of context" is the standard sequence for this case. (It is not clear from your description if you picked the last but that's a detail.)

Opinions on the closure of such questions just are mixed; some are of the opinion nothing should be done in such a case. Thus, a declined flag can happen and is not a big deal.

If a considerable proportion of your flags is declined you might reconsider your standards though.

Anyway, the flag was the correct one. It may be you should not have flagged at all, but there is no other flag you should have used.